# how to update the index of item in List?

Tags: c#, .net, list

I have the following list:

```
var list = new List<string>(); 

//

list.Add("foo");
list.Add("baa");
```

do something..

```
if(foo) {
  //how to put baa in as first element in list?
}
```

I'm looking for alternative for this:

```
string item = "baa";
docTypes.Remove(item);
docTypes.Insert(0, item);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no alternative, that's how you do it. If you want a bit of an efficiency improvement and you know the index, then you could use `RemoveAt`:

```
int index = 1;
docTypes.Insert(0, docTypes[index]);
docTypes.RemoveAt(index + 1);
```